# Common datastructure library in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Hello I have started writing common data structure library in C similar to STL.
Here is the link . http://code.google.com/p/cstl/

I struggled a lot of whether to go ahead with having `void*` as basic element for data structure. and End up with structure which has two elements

```
typedef struct __c_lib__object {
    void* raw_data;
    size_t size;
} clib_object, *clib_object_ptr;
```

This approach allow me to store each element, but it requires lot of memory allocation , during saving and returning back the element from the container.

Can anybody please review this , and let me know if there is any other approach.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: I wonder if you would do better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: A C library similar to STL? You mean like this (http://apr.apache.org/) or this (http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names starting with double-underscore are reserved to 'the implementation' and should be avoided in user code.

Personally, I dislike typedefs for pointers; I'd rather use `clib_object *x;` than `clib_object_ptr x;`.

Why do you need to record the size of the object?

Comment: so that when I return the object , can can make a copy of the same. unless I know the size I cannot make a copy of it.

Comment: Actually I fail to understand the usage of typedef, why it is considered as bad in C programming.

Comment: @Avinash: `typedef` is not bad; what I dislike is `typedef struct something *something_ptr;`, most of the time.  If the calling code is never going to access anything inside the structure, then it is OK, but you don't need to publish the structure details in the public header.

Comment: @Avinash: regarding the size - OK, that's fair enough.  It means that the corresponding create method is going to have to take a size argument.  That is a nuisance, but pretty much unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, create methods does take size, only problem I see when run through the profiler is lot of calls to malloc.